# Total exterior Product

Tags: reference-request, terminology, ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

In his paper [Gaussian maps and plethysm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.12.771&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Manivel uses the term "total exterior product" of line bundles, appearing for the first time on page 3. Given two (projective) varieties $V_1$ and $V_2$ and sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_{V_i}$-modules $\mathcal{F}_i$ (possibly line bundles), there should be some way to construct a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $V_1\times V_2$ which we call the **total exterior product** of $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$. However, I was unable to find a formal definition anywhere in the literature. So, my question is, what *is* the total exterior product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is meant by this is the usual *external* tensor product: if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are projections from $V_1\times V_2$ to $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively, the external tensor product $\mathcal{F}_1\boxtimes\mathcal{F}_2$ is nothing but $p_1^*(\mathcal{F}_1)\otimes p_2^*(\mathcal{F}_2)$.

Comment: Oh! Well of course, that seems perfectly reasonable. I was thinking in the completely wrong direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The word "total" may refer to the situation when you are dealing with complexes of sheaves (then the exterior tensor product is a bicomplex and you take the total complex associated with it). If these are line bundles, it is likely that "total" does not mean much.